# place div in bottom of browser

Tags: jquery, html, css

here is a screenshot of what my problem is:
[image]

i want to put the footer in the bottom of the page, even if the content's height enough to push the footer all the way down.

I know about position: fixed, but thats not a solution for me. some pages has lots of content and thats not a problem, and other pages has little bit content, and then this problem happens.

the entire footer content is put inside a div

```
border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
background: #eee;
text-align: left;
height: 170px;
padding: 15px 10px 5px 10px;
margin: 0px !important;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

any solutions?

edit: 
Here is how my Source looks like, unfortunatly i can't copy/paste my HTML source because its running a Joomla template, and the codes are from different modules.

[image]

This screenshot shows how my source looks like:
both my body and html are "height 100% !important;" if i change my body-innerwrapper to 100%, the site is destroyed and the scrolling doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Your options are position:fixed or position:absolute.

Answer (score 7):

You already have `position: absolute` set on the footer, so just add `bottom: 0` to it. The only caveat is to make sure that you set the `height` of all containers (including `body` and `html`) to `100%`:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#my-container {
    height: 100%;
    /* generic styling */
}
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    /* other rules here... */
}
```

Comment: Okay then take this +1

Comment: @Rory thanks, it works in some cases, and doesn't in some. when the content isn't filling the height of the browser, it works fine, but if there is a page where i have to scroll down, then the footer sticks to the middle of the page and isn't at the bottom. i dont know way? its a Joomla template so it makes lots of random <div> tags.

Comment: That's where the `height: 100%` on all parent elements comes in. Could you edit your question to include a sample of your actual HTML?

Comment: I tried to edit it and show you the source, sorry i edited your post to by mistake??

Answer (score 0):

Just to offer an alternative approach, if your page layout is such that you don't want to depend on `position:absolute`, you could use the `vh` unit instead. (This will not work in older browsers, and only if your footer has a fixed height. It would need further adjusting for any elements that appear before your content block.)

```css
.content, .footer {border: 1px solid;}
.content { min-height: calc(100vh - 170px); }
.footer { height: 170px; }
```

```html
<div class="content">This is the content.</div>
<div class="footer">This is the footer.</div>
```

Comment: Hello Daniel. this one doesn't work unfortunately. i dont know why.

Comment: @Peter I added a more complete snippet  (best viewed in full page) so you can see it in action.